# how to change archive repositories in 14.04

Tags: package-management

Could not save the file “/etc/apt/sources.list”.

You do not have the permissions necessary to save the file. Please check that you typed the location correctly and try again.

Comment: use sudo to edit a file `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: Also clarify that how did you (tried to) make change file: `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to change repository is to install a package manager like Synaptic, using terminal: `sudo apt-get install synaptic`. Once installed, run Synaptic and access menu "Settings -> Repositories". The rest should be quite straight forward.

If you are trying to edit files that require root permission:

- Using GEdit, you need to run the GEdit with root permission first.
  Press "Alt+F2" then type in `gksu gedit`. If you do not already have
  gksu, install it by typing `sudo apt-get install gksu` in the
  terminal.
- More direct approach would be to just type this straight in the
  terminal: `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.lst`, then edit and save the
  file.

Comment: how to replace complete source list and code for that??

Comment: For a complete guide to do that please refer to the following Ubuntu documentation page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine